# Why is the CSS border-color inheriting the color property?

Tags: css

Is it normal that a border color would be inherited from font's `color` property? I was surprised to find that:

```css
div
{
 border: 4px solid;
 color: red;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/muzefigubi/edit?html,css,output)

gives me a div with a red border. Usually not specifying a color will default to black. What is this odd inheritance?

[image]

Comment: This question is the inverse of [Set CSS Border Color to text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663510/set-css-border-color-to-text-color)

Comment: thats the default property! its meant to work that way

Comment: As pointed out by @BoltClock in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34669080/3597276), this is not an issue of inheritance, as that can only be passed on from parents to children of the same property.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Based on [section 4.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-color) of the relevant [Backgrounds and Borders Module spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background), the initial `border-color` value is [`currentColor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#currentcolor):

> [**CSS Color Module - 4.4. `currentColor` color keyword**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#currentcolor)
>
> CSS1 and CSS2 defined the initial value of the `border-color` property to be the value of the `color` property but did not define a corresponding keyword. This omission was recognized by SVG, and thus SVG 1.0 introduced the `currentColor` value for the `fill`, `stroke`, `stop-color`, `flood-color`, and `lighting-color` properties.
>
> CSS3 extends the color value to include the `currentColor` keyword to allow its use with all properties that accept a <color> value. This simplifies the definition of those properties in CSS3.

In other words, the value is treated as the following in your case:

```
border: 4px solid currentColor;
```

Therefore you could also use the `currentColor` value for something such as the `background-color` property. For instance:

```css
div {
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid;
  background-color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Small fun fact, if you change the font color (e.g. `:hover`), the bordercolor changes with it! [It also works well with transitions!](https://jsfiddle.net/kpk5debr/)

Comment: Just to add that it has been this way since CSS 1 (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#border-color).

Comment: This also works well when changing the color, and it keeps working with animation! Added a fiddle to the post

Comment: @Martijn: I'm surprised it works considering in your fiddle you specified the transition property to be `color`, only. In IE, you need to specify both `color, border-color` in order for the border to animate along with the color. IE's behavior is more in line with what I'd expect, but I don't know whose behavior is actually correct.

Comment: IMO it works as expected. You don't define the bordercolor so you're defining it to be the same as the text. Text color changes, thus bordercolor... But relying on textcolor for a bordercolor isn't the best practice anyway

Answer (score 17):

In CSS, an element can have one of two "primary" colors: a foreground color, specified by the `color` property, and a background color, specified by the `background-color` property. Lots of other properties accept a color, but having black as the initial color value would be very arbitrary, so instead properties that accept a color value take on the computed foreground color by default.

Of course, this *can* result in a black border if the foreground color is black, but only then. And the text color is only black to start with because the default UA stylesheets make it so; CSS does not state anywhere that the initial value should be black, but that it is UA-dependent ([CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#color), [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#colors), [CSS Color 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#foreground)). For example, a UA in high-contrast mode or inverted-colors mode could specify the default color scheme to be white on black, or a different color combination entirely:

[image: Windows High Contrast Demo]

This behavior has been around since [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#border-color). The `currentColor` value, introduced in [CSS Color 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#currentcolor) based on the equivalent SVG keyword, is now listed as the initial value of the respective properties in the respective CSS3 modules:

- [`border-color`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-color)
- [`outline-color`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#outline-color)<sup>1</sup>
- [`box-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow)

Using `attr()` with a color value *also* falls back to `currentColor` when a value cannot be found. See [CSS Values 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#attr-notation).

Prior to CSS3 there was no way to restore the color of a border or outline to the computed foreground color once overridden; see my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663510/set-css-border-color-to-text-color/8663547#8663547). While this question uses the word "inherit", it should be noted that specifying `border-color: inherit` *does not* inherit from the `color` property — like all other CSS properties, it inherits from the `border-color` of the parent element.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The default is actually to invert the colors of the pixels underneath the outline, but supporting `invert` is not mandatory and if a browser chooses not to, the foreground color must be used instead.</sub>

Comment: @BoltClock How do you "restore the color of a border or outline to the computed foreground color once overridden"? Your (other) answer does not mention this.

Comment: @Matt: It mentions using currentColor.