# Why does table <td> border color inherit from <tr> element color?

Tags: html, css

I just notice that if I set "tr" element color to red, then "td" border color is also set to red. Is it a browser's bug?

https://jsfiddle.net/tbgggu62/3/

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="color: red;">
            <td >A</td>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spaceUnder">
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rbm8.jpg]

Thanks.

Comment: This is essentially already answered in [Why is the CSS border-color inheriting the the color property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667409/why-is-the-css-border-color-inheriting-the-the-color-property) - the only difference here is that the td is inheriting the specified value of color from its parent tr, which then gets applied to its own borders exactly as described in the link.

Comment: As far as i understand, TR is virtual element, TD is visual. Logic says, yes, it's inherited and that should be normal behavior, not a bug. Anyway, I'm not an expert in this area, better seek for another opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug.  You have set the color for the `tr` to `red`, the `td` inherits `color` from its parent and is therefore also `red`. Lastly, you have set the `border-style` and `border-width` of the `td`, but you did not set the `border-color`.  `border-color` [defaults to `currentcolor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color), which is the text color of the element: in this case `red`.

Through a series of inheritance and default values, it is working as intended.

Comment: I think OP expected to just change the text color. But he also show change in color of border. So, he asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph Marikle said the color is inherited by default.  Since it was set at the tr level everything under it will also be set to red unless you don't want it to be.

to leave the text red, but change the border color use this:

```
td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color:black;
}
```

or use shorthand(it saves space)

```
td {
  border:solid 1px black;
}
```

to have the border red, but change the text color in the first row do this:

```
td {
  border:solid 1px;
}

tr:nth-child(1) td{
  color:black;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```