# CSS - Reason for border-X-color not applied after a call to element[attribute^=value]

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup :

**HTML**

```
 <article class="card big-number border-green">     
   <p class="number">5</p>
  </article><!-- /card-two -->
```

**CSS**

```
article[class^='border-'], article[class*=' border-'] {
    border-left : 1px solid ;
}

.border-yellow {
   border-left-color: yellow;
}
.border-green {
       border-left-color:  green;
}
.border-blue {
      border-left-color:  blue;
}
.border-red {
      border-left-color:  red;
}
```

The issue is that the colors are not being applied, unless I specify element like so :

```
article.border-red {
          border-left-color:  red;
    }
```

I know I can resolve it using a catch-all rule like

```
[class^='border-'], [class*=' border-']
```

but the reason for the question is that I would very much like to understand the REASON for that behavior. isn't '`border-color`' considered a rule for ANY element that contains this class ( including '`article'` in my case ..) and have a declared border property ?

Tested on Chrome, Firefox .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
Ok so the real issue here is that the `border-left-color` gets overridden by the value from `border-left : 5px solid;` (which is [currentColor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34667435/10825793)).

Why?
The culprit here is

```
article[class^='border-'], article[class*=' border-'] {
    border-left : 1px solid ;
}
```

which has **higher [specifity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez60W.png)** than `.border-green`
See [Specificity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

[image: Specificity Calculator]

---

The reason is that `border-left : 1px solid;`
sets the border color to [currentColor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34667435/10825793) (black) for each article.
This overrules the `border-left-color` of the .border-green class.
Notice how adding `!important` to .border-green changes the output.

```css
article[class^='border-'], article[class*=' border-'] {
    border-left : 5px solid ;
}

.border-yellow {
   border-left-color: yellow;
}
.border-green {
       border-left-color:  green !important;
}
.border-blue {
      border-left-color:  blue;
}
.border-red {
      border-left-color:  red;
}
```

```html
 <article class="card big-number border-green">     
   <p class="number ">5</p>
  </article><!-- /card-two -->
```

[image: .border-green gets overriden]

Comment: but by the transitive property ( cascading ) of CSS , if the `.border-color` rule comes **after** the general rule in order of inclusion, shouldn't that be applied ? my question is exactly that - **why** it is overridden ..

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will try to read more about specificity. TNX.. .