# Font color is interfering with border color (jsfiddle)

Tags: html, css

I have a class for a specific font color, and another class for a border color. When I assign an element the class for both, the font color class takes over for both the font and the border.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/e81jrzfu/

```
html {
  background: #fff;
}
.border-gold {
  border-color: #f4cc55;
}
.color-red {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.midquote {
        display: block;
        margin: 1em;
        padding: 0.6em;
        text-align: center;
        border-top: 0.12em dashed; 
        border-bottom: 0.2em solid;
    }
    .midquote .icon {
        display: block;
        margin-top: -1.4em; 
    }
    .midquote i {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 0 0.6em 0 0.6em;
    }

    .quoting {
        display: block;
    }
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="midquote color-red border-gold">

   <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
   This is an amazing quote from someone.
   <span class="quoting">Jon Doe</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the way you've specified your borders in the `.midquote` rule:

```
border-top: 0.12em dashed; 
border-bottom: 0.2em solid;
```

These reset the `border-color` declaration from your `.border-gold` rule to currentColor, which refers to the `color` property. [This is expected behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663510/set-css-border-color-to-text-color/8663547#8663547)

You can fix this by [using the longhands instead of the shorthands](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/e81jrzfu/1):

```
.midquote {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0.6em;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-width: 0.12em;
    border-top-style: dashed;
    border-bottom-width: 0.2em;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

Or you can rearrange the rules so `.midquote` comes before all the others (which is probably what you intended).

Answer (score 1):

You can just increase [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of `border-gold` selector like this `.midquote.border-gold` or `div.border-gold`

> **What is Specificity?**
>
> If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity wins

```css
html {
  background: #fff;
}
.midquote.border-gold {
  border-color: #f4cc55;
}
.color-red {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.midquote {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.6em;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 0.12em dashed;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid;
}
.midquote .icon {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -1.4em;
}
.midquote i {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 0.6em 0 0.6em;
}
.quoting {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="midquote color-red border-gold">

  <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span> This is an amazing quote from someone.
  <span class="quoting">Jon Doe</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your border shorthand rules in your `.midquote` selector are overriding the style you set with `.border-gold`. The easiest solution is to either just move the `.border-gold` after the `.midquote` rule, or increase the specificity of the `.border-gold` rule (e.g. `div.border-gold`).

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gonhgg6m/)** (moved rule)

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g64qs58b/)** (increase specificity)

Answer (score -1):

if i understand it correctly you need to add *!important* for *.border-gold* for this as follow:

```
.border-gold {
  border-color: #f4cc55 !important;
}
.color-red {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```